Deserializing a XML into an Object code does not work
I have a issue with deserializing and XML within Symfony. I tried the normal Symfony Serializer but its not working there either.
As far as I can see everyting seems to be correct but I dont see the issue.
Controller:
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\DataObjects\Dossiers;
use JMS\Serializer\SerializerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

#[Route('/test')]
class TestController extends AbstractController
{
    private $serializer;

    public function __construct(SerializerInterface $serializer)
    {
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
    }

    #[Route('/')]
    public function test(): Response
    {
        $xmlContent = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
        <Dossiers source="Source" type="myType">
            <Dossier>
                <Name>Name</Name>
                <Description>Description</Description>
            </Dossier>
        </Dossiers>';

        // Deserialisieren Sie den XML-Inhalt
        $dossiers = $this->serializer->deserialize($xmlContent, Dossiers::class, 'xml');

        // Debugging
        echo "Source: " . $dossiers->getSource() . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $dossiers->getType() . "<br>";
        echo "Dossiers:<br>";
        foreach ($dossiers->getDossiers() as $dossier) {
            echo "  Name: " . $dossier->getName() . "<br>";
            echo "  Description: " . $dossier->getDescription() . "<br>";
        }

        dd($dossiers);
        return new Response('Parsed XML');
    }
}

App\DataObjects\Dossiers:

<?php
namespace App\DataObjects;

use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;

/**
 * @JMS\XmlRoot("Dossiers")
 */
class Dossiers
{
    /**
     * @JMS\XmlAttribute
     * @JMS\SerializedName("source")
     * @JMS\Type("string")
     */
    private $source;

    /**
     * @JMS\XmlAttribute
     * @JMS\SerializedName("type")
     * @JMS\Type("string")
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @JMS\SerializedName("Dossier")
     * @JMS\Type("array<App\DataObjects\Dossier>")
     * @JMS\XmlList(inline = true, entry = "Dossier")
     */
    private $dossiers = [];

    public function getSource()
    {
        return $this->source;
    }

    public function setSource($source)
    {
        $this->source = $source;
    }

    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    public function setType($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;
    }

    public function getDossiers()
    {
        return $this->dossiers;
    }

    public function setDossiers(array $dossiers)
    {
        $this->dossiers = $dossiers;
    }
}

App\DataObjects\Dossier:
<?php

namespace App\DataObjects;

use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;

class Dossier
{
    /**
     * @JMS\XmlElement(cdata=false)
     * @JMS\SerializedName("Name")
     * @JMS\Type("string")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @JMS\XmlElement(cdata=false)
     * @JMS\SerializedName("Description")
     * @JMS\Type("string")
     */
    private $description;

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;
    }
}


Return at the moment:
Source:
Type:
Dossiers:

 App\DataObjects\Dossiers {#146 ▼
  -source: null
  -type: null
  -dossiers: []
}

What I want is for the XML to be put into the DataObjects so that I can use the DataObject later for more complex stuff.

You have shown us the code and told us what your goal is but, you have not told us what the "issue" actually is that you are experiencing. What happens when you visit the route '/test/' ?

Oh sorry. What actually happens is that I get nothing back.
The Return Value for the Above code in Symfony 7 is this here:
Source:
Type:
Dossiers:
App\DataObjects\Dossiers {#146 ▼
-source: null
-type: null
-dossiers: []
}

Have you tried serializing to double check the structure of your xml matches? I think maybe you need to wrap the items in the field? <Dossiers ... ><dossiers><Dossier></...>

The XML is not made up by me but given to me and I can't change anything about the design of the XML.
Its <Dossiers ...> I wouldnt even make this structure as Dossier is always alone.

Ok, I found some examples that match, but that (reversing your sample test) would be a way to check that everything is configured correctly.

Seems like we got here something.
$testDossiers = new Dossiers('TestSource', 'TestType', new Dossier('TestName'));
produces:


TestName

Which looks kind of wrong.

I Found the problem.
The JMS Serializer gives you a bit more Annotation then I used. So I added a XmlRoot and a XmlNamespace at the start of the first class to handle my whole XML correctly. now it works.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
        <atom:Dossiers xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" source="TestSource" type="TestType">
            <atom:Dossier>
                <atom:Name>Name</atom:Name>

#[JMS\XmlRoot("Dossiers")]
#[JMS\XmlNamespace(uri:"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom", prefix:"atom")]
class Dossiers
{
    /**
     * @JMS\XmlAttribute
     * @JMS\SerializedName("source")
     * @JMS\Type("string")
     */
    private $source;

    /**
     * @JMS\XmlAttribute
     * @JMS\SerializedName("type")
     * @JMS\Type("string")
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @JMS\SerializedName("Dossier")
     * @JMS\Type("App\DataObjects\Dossier")
     * @JMS\XmlElement(cdata=false, namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
     */



Your custom XML tags are not valid ATOM. I suggest you use your own namespace (uri) and prefix.

I'm using my own just changed it to atom to make it anonym
